Trying to resolve csrf token error, I have tried disabling for the particular api and also used @CrossOrigin at contoller level, nothing seems to work
Using Spring Security 6.3.3.

`    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
        return http.build();
    }`


2024-09-17T11:38:49.182-04:00 DEBUG 17147 --- [orderhub] [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/drivers/register
2024-09-17T11:38:49.183-04:00 DEBUG 17147 --- [orderhub] [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/api/drivers/register
2024-09-17T11:38:49.183-04:00 DEBUG 17147 --- [orderhub] [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
2024-09-17T11:38:49.184-04:00 DEBUG 17147 --- [orderhub] [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2024-09-17T11:38:49.184-04:00 DEBUG 17147 --- [orderhub] [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-09-17T11:38:49.190-04:00 DEBUG 17147 --- [orderhub] [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using And [Not [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@75579691, matchingMediaTypes=[application/xhtml+xml, image/*, text/html, text/plain], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
2024-09-17T11:38:49.190-04:00 DEBUG 17147 --- [orderhub] [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using Or [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest], And [Not [MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@75579691, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@75579691, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@75579691, matchingMediaTypes=[*/*], useEquals=true, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]]
2024-09-17T11:38:49.190-04:00 DEBUG 17147 --- [orderhub] [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint@f04b3b6
2024-09-17T11:38:49.190-04:00 DEBUG 17147 --- [orderhub] [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2024-09-17T11:38:49.190-04:00 DEBUG 17147 --- [orderhub] [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@33c99aca

I have tried at controller level with annotation @CrossOrigin, also tried with the specific Api pattern matching
 @PostMapping("/register")
@CrossOrigin
public ResponseEntity<List<Driver>> registerDrivers(@RequestBody List<Driver> drivers) {
    List<Driver> registeredDrivers = driverService.registerDriver(drivers);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(registeredDrivers);
}


Why the empty requestMatcher string? .requestMatchers("").authenticated() - Do you want to have the root context path authenticated?

Yes, That was my idea. but seems like it's not working.

You need to use authorizeHttpRequests since Spring Security 6.0.0 I believe. Modified from your question code.
Updated the answer to disable cors.
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) ->
        authorizeHttpRequests
           .requestMatchers("").authenticated()
           .anyRequest().permitAll()
        )
    .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    .cors { it.disable() }
    return http.build();
}

Also, if you want, you can add a fairly liberal corsMapping bean:
@Bean
fun corsMappingConfiguration(): WebFluxConfigurer {
    return object : WebFluxConfigurer {
        override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOriginPatterns(corsProperties.allowedOriginPatterns.joinToString())
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600)
        }
    }
}


Yes I did try this before with the pattern matching
' .requestMatchers("/api/drivers/register").authenticated()', it's not working either.

Updated the answer to include .cors { it.disable() }. I misread the issue in the question.

I still see the same after changing
